# Backup strategy to loose almost no data from VMs - no HA cluster

Tags: virtual-machine, backup, vmware

We are using 3 VMware ESXi Hosts with 10 Vms.
Last week one of the Hosts crashed (raid controller corrupt), loosing all the data of this machine.
I had to get the backup from the day before, wich took a day (so all employeed had to go home for a day) and we lost all work of that day.

We cannot afford a HA cluster, so I am looking for ideas to

- loose (almost) no data
- get quicker restores - to loose (almost) no time

Currently we use Veeam to make Backups and Replicas of the VMs.

These are the ideas I have so far:

a) making one full backup (takes one day) and then incrementals every hour during the work hours
Problems:

- too long restore time
- having work from 7 to 18 on 5 days, that would be 55 incrementals (don't know if that is stable)

b) making a full backup every night and then incrementals every hour during work hours
Problems:

- too long restore time
- backup might take longer than the night

c) making a full replica every night and then incremental replicas every hour

- restore time is ok
- maybe problems deleting the snapshots

How do you handle the Problem, when you don't want to loose any data?

Comment: If they are taking too long the question here is what kind of Ethernet speeds are we dealing with?  If you have 1gbit, get 10gbit,40gbit. Dual,Quad NIC... How many gb/s is your storage?  M.2 SSD?  Obviously faster storage can dramatically reduce your times.

Comment: Maybe replace your RAID with ZFS. With the right configuration, this can dramatically reduce the chances of failure. Keep the daily backups but hopefully you never need it.